# C#: Non-generic interfaces w/generic methods, generic implementation… (compile time) type safety?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, implementation

There probably are threads here that explain it, but my google fu seems not to be good enough to find them.

I have a pretty common problem: I want to have a non-generic interface that I can put in some kind of enumerable, but ONE of the interface's methods will have a generic input parameter, but as an input parameter, its type is inferable.

For various reasons, I want my *implementation* to be generic, because the input parameter mentioned above is being used in a few more places in the implementation, among others as type of a property.

Let me give you an example of how it might be implemented to make clearer what I mean:

```cs
public interface IThreshold
{
    /* various (non-generic) methods and properties */
    bool ThresholdExceeded<T>(T value) where T : IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>;
}

public class Threshold<T> : IThreshold where T : IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
{
    /* various (non-generic) methods and properties */
    T ThresholdValue { get; }
    bool IThreshold.ThresholdExceeded<U>(U value) where U : IComparable<U>, IEquatable<U> => ThresholdExceeded((T)(object)value);
    public bool ThresholdExceeded(T value)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

[…]
((IThreshold)thresholdOfIntInstance).ThresholdExceeded(5) ? DoSomething();
```

This will work (unless I introduced an error when simplifying it for the example), *however*, type safety is of course out the window with the `(T)(object)value` cast.
Of course I'd rather have a compile time type check than a possible runtime InvalidCastException.
But at the same time, I can't simply use my implementation's `T` as the `ThresholdExceeded` input type, since

- if I leave out the `IThreshold.ThresholdExceeded<U>`, it will not recogise `ThresholdExceeded(T value)` as the implementation of the interface method (of course, the T isn't the same to the compiler)
- if I change the constraints for `IThreshold.ThresholdExceeded<U>` to `where U : IComparable<U>, IEquatable<U>, T` or something similar, the compiler complains that the constraints in the implementation don't match the interface anymore (I wonder why, since they're only *stricter*, but ah well)

Is there a pattern that allows me to implement this in a way to keep both *compile time* type checking AND the comfort of calling the interface method with any kind of type without casting to a specific implementation first (and, of course, while keeping the interface itself non-generic, so that I can have multiple generic instances in an IEnumerable and call the method on them without casting them first)?

Comment: Maybe try `bool IThreshold.ThresholdExceeded<U>(U value) where U : T, IComparable<U>, IEquatable<U>` so that the compiler knows that U and T are the same?

Comment: Does `public bool ThresholdExceeded<T>(T value)` work? Just adding the `<T>` after the method name.

Comment: If that thing from my comment works the `where U : T` part might even be sufficient, since it knows that T is Comparable. But the question is how well that works together with satisfying the interface condition.

Comment: "...I wonder why, since they're only stricter". If they're stricter, they are not the same. One method would accept types the other does not accept.

Comment: @Matthias247 that's what I first thought, too, that's my bullet point 2 above, (but I did get the error mixed up)—tried again, VS2015 tells me "Error CS0460: Constraints for override and explicit interface implementation methods are inherited from the base method, so they cannot be specified directly". But in the end it's the same, I'm not able to add that constraint.

Comment: I tested it too. You can add it by using either a third method or making `bool ThresholdExceeded` also generic and add it there. However the `: T` approach also doesn't work, since it means the class is derived from the other, not that it's the same. And whether it's derived can't be proven by the compiler.

Comment: @Matthias247 I also tried something else inspired by your comment: put in a proxy method:

"bool IValueWarningEntry.ThresholdExceeded<U>(U value) => ThresholdExceededProxy(value);"

"private bool ThresholdExceededProxy<V>(V value) where V: T, IComparable<V>, IEquatable<V> => ThresholdExceeded(value);"

But then, again, there's no boxing conversion from U to V.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen nope. Then it just tells you this T and the class's T are not the same and warns about them having the same name.

Comment: @Dennis_E …you're of course right. m) Dunno why my brain farted there :P

Comment: I think it cannot be done as you would like to. Your interface specifies that ANY type which implements IComparable and IEquatable can be passed to ThresholdExceeded method, and that always can be not the same type you declared for your Threshold<T> implementation.

Comment: @Evk Yes, and that's exactly the time when I'd want a compile error to be thrown, that's what I'm after!

Comment: But this cannot be done, in principle. Suppose you have Threshold<string>. Then you cast it to your interface, because it implements it. Now you have IThreshold. Now, nothing can prevent you pass any comparable value to ThresholdExceeded method, because your interface does not put any restrictions on the type. You can happily pass integer there and all will be correct. So there is no place where compiler error might be thrown here.

Comment: @Evk Ok, yeah, I think I see where you're coming from, I had it backwards in my head. Too little coffee this morning, I suppose.